# Why are the Tau so resistant to Chaos?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Of the major races in the WH40k universe, humans seem uniquely tempted by chaos. Some minor races are mentioned to be chaos worshippers like the Laer so chaos is not uniquely human.

Why are the Tau so resistant to Chaos? If it is because of their devotion to the ethereals, then why are all the ethereals so resistant to chaos?

Comment: My understanding was that the capacity for being a psyker - and by extension, being attuned with the warp - is a mutation representing the next stage in human evolution, which mankind is slowly moving into. The T'au, being a much younger race, have yet to "discover" this mutation.

Comment: My impression has been that humans are less *inherently* susceptible to Chaos than Eldar, but the Eldar have created a whole society and way of life based on resisting and distancing themselves from Chaos, so humans are more likely to fall prey to Chaos on than Eldar in practice.

Comment: @ToddWilcox This is indeed the case for the Eldar but this question is about the Tau(?)

Comment: @Ummdustry My comment was meant to suggest a clarification/edit to the question, in that humans are not "uniquely tempted by Chaos".

Comment: Ah i see now, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tau are not resistant to Chaos they are simply less connected to it.
if you were to draw a scale from normal human to psykers to farseers of "connection to the warp" then Tau would be off the scale towards the human end meaning they have little connection to the warp and thus rarely get corrupted by chaos. This can also be seen in the fact they have no known natural psykers among their ranks.

As for why they are so unconnected to the warp the simple answer is that we don't know. it's possible that it's simply how they evolved but a lot of fan theories give one reason or another (my personal favourite being that they are related to the necrontyr.) but we won't know for sure till GW gives us a definite reason.

Also see:

Comment: Aren't they also fairly unemotional in general? Seems like degree of emotional sensitivity has something to do with Chaos and the Warp - as seen in the Fall of the Eldar.

Comment: This is certainly true. we know its not a perfect correlation (blanks still have emotions, most psychers aren't total divas, zoanthropes are actually fairly chill as tyranids go). but there is definately a degree to which emotion increases connection to the warp that being said i have no idea how emotional the Tau are since I haven't read enough to get a feel for it I was under the impression they where about as emotional as humans.

Comment: This would be improved by citing actual material, either army books,game books or novels